# decrementing/incrementing trigger on mysql

Tags: mysql, triggers

im making a decrementing and incrementing trigger for my money field in table user , lets say i have these 2 table

```
Table: user
---------------
|Name      | Clark |
|id_store  |  1    |
|id_user   |  1    |
|money     |  200  |

|Name      | kent  |
|id_store  |  2    |
|id_user   |  2    |
|money     |  400  |
---------------

Table: item
---------------
|id item   |    1 |
|item name | books|
|id_user   |    1 |
---------------
```

when user 2 bought books, user 2 money should be decrementing by 200 while the user 1 money should be incremented by 200

the question is, how do i do that? should i create 2 trigger ?

Comment: Wierd table structure is it really like that you did you make a mistake when generating the ascii data..